# Visual Studio 2012 c++ intellisense comments for std possible?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++11, visual-studio-2012

Is it possible to get comments on c++11 std methods and classes in VS2012 ? Currently i'm only seeing parameters and return types - and they're a mouthful to interpret for someone learning cpp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Only if comments are written before the function declaration, which they are not for VS2012 STL implementation, unfortunately (maybe for parsing speed reasons though, maybe not).

Always refer to either the MSDN (type F1 while having the cursor on the name of the function or type), or refer to the standard. I often use http://en.cppreference.com as a reference for everything in the standard.